# Display all types of messages sent to View in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I return to the index Route after various actions in various controller methods in Laravel. In different methods, I send different messages such as "success", "error" and... to the index Route.
The index Route directs me to a blade file. How can I receive and display any type of message sent by different methods with just one coding?
Currently I send messages with "with".
for example:

```
number 1 method(){
   //some Code
   return to_route('sms.index')->with('error - '.$resultText);
}
number 2 method(){
   //some Code
   return to_route('sms.index')->with('success','action is success');
}
```

But on the view side, I have to write a piece of code like the following for each one:

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <span>{{session('success')}}</span>
    </div>
@endif
```

and

```
@if(session()->has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <span>{{session('error')}}</span>
    </div>
@endif
```

Is it possible to combine all of these? Or at least did the job with less code?

Comment: You can use a component: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#components

Comment: use these in your layout or use component or use sweet alert realrashid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like:

```php
return to_route('sms.index')->with('flash-msg', ['type' => 'danger', 'message' => $resultText]);

// layout.blade.php
@if(session()->has('flash-msg'))
    @php $flash_msg = session('flash-msg'); @endphp
    <div class="alert alert-{{ $flash_msg['type'] ?? 'success' }}">
        <span>{{ $flash_msg['message'] }}</span>
    </div>
@endif
```